# Proper usage of PHP Sessions

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-cookies, logout

I'm using PHP and MySQL to create a web portal for users to login and access various tools using a single sign-on method. Some of the tools include phpMyAdmin and Piwik. The landing page will show all the tools they can use without having to login individually.

The session is called "Portal".

I have the following files:
index.php - checks to see if they are logged in or not. If logged in, displays a page with a list of tools.

login.php - provides a login form, creates the session, and redirects back to index.php if authorized

logout.php - provides a logout function to destroy session.

Since I haven't used PHP in the past 4 years, I am aware a lot has possibly changed.

Below is the scripts used for each page.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || (trim($_SESSION['pass']) == '')) {
header("location: login.php");
exit();
} else }
  // show list of tools (secure area)
}

?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', 0); // NOT SURE WHAT THIS DOES?
  session_name("Portal");
  session_start();

  // check if credentials match
  ...code...

  // if credentials are ok
  $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
  $_SESSION['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
  session_write_close();
  header('Location: index.php');
} else {
  // show login form
}
?>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) { // !not sure what all this below does!
  $params = session_get_cookie_params();
  setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 4200,
  $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
}
session_destroy();
header('Location: http://.../index.php');
?>
```

How do I delete a specific session, ie Portal? I have another login at the root domain to access reports and I don't want users who have access to both get logged out of both sessions, but just the portal.

Is there anything that needs to be changed in my coding that may improve/enhance security?

Thanks!

Comment: for starters, don't put the user's password in the session. you also don't need to explicitly call `session_write_close`.

Comment: I wouldn't do this at all.  Use the proper methods for SSO for your applications.  If they don't have them, don't do it.  Do not replay the user's password to the other application... it generally won't work, and isn't secure at all.

Comment: @Mark, in deed there are some problems with sessions and redirecting with `header`. I've always experienced this in Windows environment with PHP until 5.2.x. I don't know if this was fixed, though. The only way of solving it was to explicitly call `session_write_close`.

Comment: phpMyAdmin supports SSO. It requests to put the password in the session (ie $_SESSION['PMA_single_signon_password'] = $_POST['pass']; )

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you don't have any server-side validation. Any user can insert whatever they want into the login fields and then access the "secured area" simply because whatever they inserted into the login fields is in a session. If you are not validating anything, I suggest putting the login information into a database and when a user logs in they have to have matching credentials that correspond with the credentials in the database.

Also, your index.php page has the bracket for else{} facing the wrong way. This should give an error.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || (trim($_SESSION['pass']) == '')) {
header("location: login.php");
exit();
} else {
  // show list of tools (secure area)
}

?>
```

Comment: I didn't want to make the post longer so I removed the section that checks the credentials. Basically I am using the mysql database and user table as those who have access to the portal.

Comment: Oh ok, that credential check will obviously make it more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some issues with your code.

First of all, you MUST call `session_name` **before** `session_start` (see the [manual](http://php.net/session_name)).

Also, **DO NOT PUT SENSITIVE DATA IN SESSIONS EVER**!

As said in docs of [session_set_cookie_params](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params), you can do this also **BEFORE** call `session_start`:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600, '/', '.yourdomain.com', false, true); // Notice the dot before the domain
```

This will allow you to have access to the session in all applications in this domain.

I don't know how can you do this work with several applications, but if they have support to single sign on, you will be able to do this **WITHOUT** putting your password there.

Comment: It's all on the same subdomain.example.com

Comment: How do I send the password that I collected from the user to another tool like phpMyAdmin if I can't store the password?

Comment: What you'll try to do is use an authentication provider with token validation. please look at oauth 2.0 , this way you do not have to move around a password ( plaintext password is always a bad idea), instead you can move about a token.